# Confusion on construction of type III factors

Tags: ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Well $G$ is group of translations: $\mathbb{R} \ni s:\mapsto as+b $ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, modulus of  $a\neq1$. Under this action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$ why Lebesgue measure is not invariant? Further but which reason  restriction of the group only left translations $\mathbb{R} \ni s:\mapsto as$ where $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ the Lebesgue measure is left invariant is not clear to me. Please give hint.

Comment: If you allow scaling: what is the image of$ [0,1] $ and what is the measure?

Comment: Why is this relevant to type III factors? Are you interested in the von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb{Q \rtimes Q^\ast}$? I am also guessing that $a \neq 1$ is a typo and you mean $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Because $G\ltimes L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mu)$ will give type III factor, reference KRII. Where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.